# Weird behavior of simple C code with float input and output values

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I cannot explain this behavior: same function with same input parameters called from two different positions gives two different answers. But it should not!

Float result is 0 in some cases and I can't explain why.

This is a simple piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  bar((1.0/16));  //prints input
  foo();          //calls bar((1.0/16));
}

void bar(float x){
  printf("%f\n",x);
}

void foo(){
  bar((1.0/16));
}
```

This is its output:

```
0.000000
0.062500
```

- this happens only with `float` type parameter and `1.0/16` value.
- no problem at all with `int` or `unsigned int` type parameter and `16` value.
- no problem at all with `float` type parameter and `16`. value.

So the problem appears only when I use both a float type and a float value.

All this happens on a Windows 7 64 bit machine in Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
Only settings I changed in project properties:

- struct member alignment: 1 byte.
- disable language extensions: yes
- compile as: compile as C code

Configuration: Debug. Platform: win32.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ecause you don't have a prototype of `bar` before you call it the first time from `main`, so the compiler will try to guess what argument type the function have, and as you pass a `double` argument to it (`1.0 / 16` is of type `double`) it will pass a `double` value to a function which actually takes a `float` argument. That mismatch in parameters leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Declare the function (write a prototype) before calling the function.
2. Change the argument type to `double`.

I recommend number 1 in the list.

It will *not* work to pass a `float` value to the function (e.g. `1.0f / 16`) since since for implicitly declared functions like yours the arguments are promoted to the default type, which for floating point values is `double`. Also note that implicitly declared functions are expected to return an `int`.

Comment: VS2010 gives no warning for missing prototypes, even at Level4 (/W4). GCC on the other hand gave the right warning at compile time. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function `bar` and `foo` without their previous declarations. When the compiler encounters the first call of `bar`/`foo`, it doesn't know about how many parameters these functions would have, what types of parameters are or what kind of value they will return.

Instead of producing any error/warning, compiler assumes that `foo` returns an `int` value (note that the return type of a function is `int` by default. But in C99 and latter this has been dropped and you will get a compilation error.) and that's why you are getting `0.000000` for first call of `foo`.

You should put a prototype before `main`.

```
void bar(float x);
void foo(void);
```